# PLINK and detectRUNS issues

Tags: r

I try to use the R package detectRUNS with the output files of PLINKs.
PLINKs gives me three files format:

```
sample.hom
sample.ped
sample.map
```

I have tried to input them into detectRUNS following the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/detectRUNS/vignettes/detectRUNS.vignette.html#importing-data-from-external-files) as following:

```
# Import .hom PLINK file in R:
runs <- readExternalRuns(inputFile = "sample.hom" , program = "plink")

# Calculate statistics ROH:
summaryList <- summaryRuns(runs = Plinkruns, mapFile = "sample.map", genotypeFile = "sample.ped", Class = 6, snpInRuns = TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
Checking files...
Using class: 2
Total genome length: 788538107
calculating Froh on all genome
Total genome length: 788538107
calculating Froh chromosome by chromosome
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: This is more suitable at GitHub: https://github.com/bioinformatics-ptp/detectRUNS

Comment: The problem is indeed discussed in the Github Issues. Thank you!